# How to use a multi value parameter from SSRS an interbase query

Tags: reporting-services, interbase

Interbase cannot accept multi value parameters with ?

It can use

`WHERE sl.Truck_Nbr IN ("A205", "A206") but not WHERE sl.Truck_Nbr IN (?)`.

I have tried using

```
="""" & (Join(Parameters!Parameter3.Value,""",""")) & """"
```

in the parameter expression and if I display the value on the report, it does display, "A205", "A206" and the interbase query does not complain but it does not return any records

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with a work around - used the parameter as a filter parameter rather than a query parameter - once the query is done via interbase, the filter performs with SSRS functionality - and is quicker updating the report when the multi parameter is re-selected